# expose OWIN authentication in WebService

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

We have a mvc5 web application that use OWIN for the authentication. Now we need to implement a mobile application for that will use the same password and login. any idea how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will you be asking the mvc5 app to return protected resources? If so, you can use ADAL.js to obtain an AccessToken.

Does the following sample seem relevant?
https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-WebAPI-AngularJS-DotNet